# Understanding a multidimensional array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have a figure and I am trying to understand it in Matlab.

```
I = imread('frame.png');
x = I(:,:,1);
y = I(:,:,2);
z = I(:,:,3);
```

In the Matlab workspace, the size of `I` is 480x640x3. I assume that this means this image has a width and height of 480 and 640 respectively, and 3 channels consisting of Red, Green, Blue.

On the other hand, the size of `x` in the workspace is 480x640, `y` is 480x640 and `z` is 480x640.

I am confused as I thought `I(:,:,1)` means give me all the rows for the first column and so, the size of `x` in the workspace should have been 480x1  and not 480x640.

Comment: There are two dimensions being indexed with `:`. Also, the first dimension is height, the second one is width.

Comment: Does this mean I am assessing the height and width of each channel? Thank you.

Comment: `I(:,:,1)` means all rows and all columns, and the first element along the 3rd dimension.

Answer (score 2):

`I(:,:,1)` gives you all the rows and columns of the first (red) channel.

To simplify this:

```
% this is a 1x4 array
oneDimensionalArray = [1, 2, 3, 4]

% this is a 2x4 array
twoDimensionalArray = [1, 2, 3, 4;
                       5, 6, 7, 8]

% this is a 2x4x2 array
threeDimensionalArray = cat(3,
                            [1, 2, 3, 4;
                             5, 6, 7, 8],
                            [ 9, 10, 11, 12;
                             13, 14, 15, 16]
                           )
```

`I` in your example is similar to threeDimensionalArray, except it has a size of 640x480x3 for every row,column and RGB channel.

threeDimensionalArray(:,:,1) will give you

```
[1, 2, 3, 4;
 5, 6, 7 ,8]
```

threeDimensionalArray(2,:,1) will give you second row of first 3rd index.

```
[5, 6, 7 ,8]
```

This mathworks tutorial has really good examples too:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I would read the tutorial now.

Comment: In MATLAB you don't make a 3D array by nesting more brackets. You need to either explicitly cat along the 3rd dimension (as the change I made to your code) or you need to use `reshape`.